# mod_rewrite some rewriterules not triggering

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am setting up an htaccess file to use some seo friendly urls instead of pointing directly to php files. I have used this method plenty before but this is my first time doing it on a rackspace server LAMP stack. It seems that some of the rules, while super simple, do not work. Only the "404error" rule seems to work, while none of the others get triggered. My apache error log shows this error:

Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/features (None could be negotiated).

.htaccess contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^features$ features.php [L]
RewriteRule ^features/$ features.php [L]

RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ blog.php [L]

RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/$ contact.php [L]

RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php [L]

RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup/$ signup.php [L]

RewriteRule ^404error$ error.php [L]
RewriteRule ^404error/$ error.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomain.com/404error
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mydomain.com/404error

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Turn on rewrite logging and post the log output for one of the accesses where the rewrite doesn't work.

Comment: I have setup error logging for mod-rewrite and posted it to pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/vTjsakM5

Comment: It appears that it only does not work when they match names. This is really odd. ie. RewriteRule ^features/?$ features.php does not work, but RewriteRule ^whatever/?$ features.php does make mydomain.com/whatever load features.php??? Is this a possible bug, or a setting that needs to be changed?

Comment: I have renamed the php files to all start with "page-"... ie. page-features.php and it works for now. The OCD part of me says this is a work around and not a real solution so I am going to leave this open hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer in your rewrite log:

12.34.56.78 - - [14/Jun/2013:19:46:18 --0700] [www.mydomain.com/sid#7fafc1a3f9b0][rid#7fafb64320a0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /features

Requested uri is `/features`. Note the initial slash.  You are matching against `^features`, with no initial slash.

Comment: Adding the forward slash does not change anything.

Comment: Can you move the rewrites to your main config (and make the patterns absolute)? Rewrites in .htaccess should be avoided.

Comment: I could. Could you provide an example of "absolute" patterns?